# Is there any way to reflect the css,js changes without running static content deploy in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, static-content-deploy

Is there any other method other than running deploy command to get new changes in the files in Magento 2?

Comment: If you are debugging something for a while. You can directly open pub folder css/js file and make changes in it. It will directly reflect the changes without running the commands. But if some one run the deploy command, than your changes will be removed.
For css reflecting directly you can just setup grunt also.

Comment: How to setup grunt in windows? Any tutorial link?

Comment: Please check for grunt setup: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/grunt/grunt_installing.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Reflect the Changes just Remove that Deployed file in `pub/static` folder

**Magento 2** will auto create the `missing/deleted static files.`

> **Created Command For Deleting this :-**
>
> rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
>   pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache
>   var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session
>   generated/code

**For Window Set Developer Mode :-**

> In Developer Mode Static view files are not cached; they are written
>   to the Magento pub/static directory every time they’re called

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: I am using windows. Please tell me the commands for windows.

Comment: set developer mode check my updated answer

Comment: I already made as developer mode but still the changes are not reflecting without running deploy content.

Comment: after mode change clear cache and then try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reflect the JS and CSS changes on the fly, you need to be set the mode to developer, the JS resources will be created as symlinks in the pub folder on the fly and the changes you made either to the ones in the pub folder or the original ones will update both of the files.

For the CSS resources, you will need to remove the compiled one in the pub folder, along with the one in the var/view_preprocessedvar/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Check this : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SOeJN6PcJI

Sorry have to entered due to character limit :)